# dlsym() returns strange address of symbol

Tags: c, symbols, dlsym

1). print function address directly:

```
printf("strerror=%p, strerror_r=%p\n", strerror, strerror_r);
strerror=0x8049ec0, strerror_r=0x8049e20
```

2). dlsym version:

```
rtldDefault= dlopen(0, RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL);
dlsym(rtldDefault, "strerror_r"); ==> strerror_r=0xb76544e0
```

but

```
dlsym(rtldDefault, "strerror"); ==> strerror=0x8049ec0
```

3). others:

```
dlsym((void*)0, "strerror_r") ==> strerror_r=0xb76544e0
dlsym((void*)-1, "strerror_r") ==> strerror_r=0xb76544e0
```

How can I get `strerror_r=0x8049e20` using `dlsym()`?

I have already print the address of strerror_r first, then call dlsym().

strerror_r=0xb76544e0 is wrong address, my call strerror_r with this address just do nothing.

Comment: I suppose it's possible that `strerror` is actually called somewhere and therefore already resolved, whereas `strerror_r` hasn't been called and `dlsym` is giving you the address of a trampoline function. Try calling them both (just once) and seeing if anything changes.

Comment: Hard to say.. Perhaps feeding it to `readelf` could give some hints

Comment: You can just look at the addresses in a debugger. I'd guess that one of them contains nothing but a jump to the real function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the declaration of `strerror_r` in `/usr/include/string.h`:

> /* Reentrant version of `strerror'.
>      There are 2 flavors of`strerror_r', GNU which returns the string
>      and may or may not use the supplied temporary buffer and POSIX one
>      which fills the string into the buffer.
>      To use the POSIX version, -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600 or -D_POSIX_C_SOURCE=200112L
>      without -D_GNU_SOURCE is needed, otherwise the GNU version is
>      preferred.  */
>      [and then some quite confusing declarations]

Compiling a sample program with `gcc -save-temps` and default configuration, I get the following precompiled declaration:

```
extern int strerror_r (int __errnum, char *__buf, size_t __buflen) 
    __asm__ ("" "__xpg_strerror_r") __attribute__ ((__nothrow__ , __leaf__))
    __attribute__ ((__nonnull__ (2)));
```

So it looks like the `strerror_r` function is linked to the symbol `__xpg_strerror_r` instead.

Indeed, a check of the generated binary `objdump -t a.out | grep strerror`:

```
00000000      DF *UND*  00000000  GLIBC_2.3.4 __xpg_strerror_r
```

So, asking your question, just do `dlsym(rtldDefault, "__xpg_strerror_r")`.

Comment: Thanks for your kindly explaination. But why dlsym(rtldDefault, "strerror_r"); ==> strerror_r=0xb76544e0

Comment: @DavidChyi: What do you mean? Why is it a much higher address than the other? Or why is it different than __xpg_strerror_r? They are different because they are different functions, or more exactly, different _symbols_. It is much higher maybe because, as Useless said in his comment, this function has never been called.